# Zuul fails to route with dynamic port microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have microservice with a dynamic port i.e, `server.port=0`.
The microservice is getting registered fine at eureka and it is up and running.

However when I am trying to access it via Zuul gateway, it fails to do with the below logs in my zuul gateway.

```
c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client: book instantiated a LoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=book,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: book.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client book initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=book,current list of Servers=[192.168.60.1:0],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {defaultzone=[Zone:defaultzone;  Instance count:1;   Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;   Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:192.168.60.1:0;    Zone:defaultZone;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@4dbc2e52
```

However when I change the port of my microservice (`book`) to non dynamic one `server.port = 8081`, everything runs fine and each time I have to restart the zuul application as well.
I guess it does not go well when one of the microservice changes port.

Let me share the `application.yml` content of both the files.

> Microservice (book), `application.yml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: book

server:
  port: 0 # I change it between 0 and 8081 (8081 works like a charm)

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
```

> Zuul `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: gatekeeper

zuul:
  routes:
    book: 
      serviceId: book

#Added it so as to increase the timeout for the underlying hysterix of the zuul

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

> Eureka server `application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

> Sring cloud version is dynamic (`${spring-cloud.version}`) with boot
>   2.1.0.release.

Comment: Out of interest, what address & port does the Eureka UI show for the service when using `0`. Is it literally `0`. Which version of spring cloud are you using. This thread might help: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/570 although it looks like even as recently as last month this setup was still causing issues: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2732

Comment: when you keep the port `0`, then a random port which is free gets allocated to the service. e.g: Now it is running with port 51995

Comment: Though Eureka shows `0`